# Preventing python from terminating if json data not found

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, elasticsearch

While iterating through json there are some files which does not have the field i am parsing (using iterator as `test_category_list = [info["Test Caps"][0]]` ). Python is terminating the execution with error `KeyError: 'Test Caps' .` I wanted give a default test_category_list if no key found. How I will do that in python ?

Comment: What about [`try/except`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html)? Catch the KeyError and assign your default value

Comment: Check `if "Test Caps" in info`.

Answer (score 2):

[`dict.get(key[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) accepts a second argument that is returned if no key is found (you can return any python object; for the example i return the string `'no_key_found'`):

```
dct = {'key': 'value'}

print(dct.get('key', 'no_key_found'))  # -> 'value'
print(dct.get('no_key', 'no_key_found'))  # -> 'no_key_found'
```

or you catch the `KeyError` in a `try/except` block:

```
try:
    ret = dct['key']
except KeyError:
    ret = 'no_key_found'
```

note: be sure to *only* catch the `KeyError` and not any other kind of exception that might occur there.

you could also check if the key exists before you access it (`if 'key' in dct: ...`); this is discouraged: the common python coding style prefers [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) over [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl).

Comment: FWIW, `None` is the default 2nd arg to `.get`, so there's no need to specify it explicitly (even though "Explicit is better than implict"). Maybe mention that in your explanation and change your example code to use a more meaningful 2nd arg.

Comment: @PM2Ring right, that was the most stupid choice for the default argument... i wanted to show that you can put stuff there. OP seems to be expecting something sequence-like. will change that.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use exceptions. They attempt to run the code in the 'try' section, and if that fails they run the except and continue through the script.

```
try:
    test_category_list = [info["Test Caps"][0]] 
except Keyerror:
    test_category_list = 'error'
```

Comment: Please change that to `except KeyError:`. A bare `except` should _only_ be used at the end of a chain of named `except`s, and even then it should (generally) re-raise the exception after it's done its special processing.